# fragment layout not corresponding to design in android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

Quick question. I have used a tab activity.
So I created fragment layouts. Then I used `getItem` method in `class SectionsPagerAdapter` with a `switch .... case` to allow swiping between those layouts.

The problem in on design. The result in AVD is different from the result in the IDE design preview... Below is my fragment xml and screenshots...

By the way, I use `inflater` in `onCreateView`as : `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_etudiant,container,false);`

**layout xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/etudiants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNouveauEtu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="INSCRIRE"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnModifEtu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="EDITER"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnListerEtu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="LISTER"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

See at the left picture (in the IDE) there are 3 buttons (`Incrire, Editer, Lister`). On the right (ie in the AVD) the 3rd button (`Lister`) is cut off

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: @tyczj See at the left there are **3** buttons. On the right (ie in the AVD) the 3rd button is cut

Comment: just looks like the emulator has a different dpi than the one you created the view on. everything looks normal to me

Comment: @tyczj Even if dpi are different, please do notice that one item is still missing and only partly shown (the 3rd button below) Plus I'm using the emulator as design device in the IDE...so....

Comment: yeah its cut off because you have your height of everything split between all the items in your linear layout, dont use a weights if you dont want this to happen. or else put it in a scrollview

Comment: @tyczj I do not understand your advice. I simply used a vertical linearlayout. I simply used weight (just as said in the doc https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) to position an ImageView and 3 Buttons... I don't understand your point

Comment: Why dont you try removing the weights from the buttons and setting the height to wrap_content and see how things change

Comment: @tyczj Same result sir. Same result. I removed all weight from buttons. Still, it's like the imageView is pushing the last button out of the UI

Comment: @tyczj The worst just happenned. Adding a scollview to emcompass all item did not change anything. The last button won't show though th UI scrolls. It's like the last button don't exist...I bet it s related to fragment and inflater but I dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the problem was but here is what I did to circumvent it  :

- I was using android studio tab activity template…
- that template uses `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` as base layout for fragment layouts
- I changed that base layout to `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`
- After that, all the suggested solutions you guyz provided and also my original code worked perfectly

Hope this helps somebody...

**Update**

I used

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

instead of

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you post your updated XML. It might help someone else who falls into the same problem.

Comment: @Sufian... Hey nice to see you again. I added my xml

Answer (score 0):

I answered you on quora ;)
The problem is more complicated than I thougth.

I suggest you to use percentage relativelayout. Once you are used to it, it solves a lot of issues and your app will fit every screen ;)

Comment: I found something :  there is a the parent view in the main layout of tab activity called `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` messes up things (dunno how to use it). When I switched it to `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` all the above techniques including yours are redundant...Everything works perfectly... So the problem is `CoordinatorLayout` vs `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Can you set `android:weightSum` attribute explicitly to `<LinearLayout>` xml element and see if that helps?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum=7>
```

Actually setting `android:weightSum` is not mandatory but I've always used it to be explicit.

Also, did you try fiddling with various values (`CENTER_CROP`, `FIT_XY` ,etc.) for `android:scaleType` to see if that helps.

Comment: Did not change anything. I found something though :  there is a the parent view in the main layout of tab activity called `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` messes up things (dunno how to use it). When I switched it to `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` all the above techniques including yours are redundant...Everything works perfectly... So the problem is `CoordinatorLayout` vs `ConstraintLayout`